# Airflow job unable to send requests to the internet

Tags: python, web-scraping, networking, airflow

I have an airflow job that does webscraping. What I realize however is that the airflow job is stuck on this line "print(requests.get("http://youtube.com"))".

Code:

```
with DAG(
    dag_id='youtube_scrape',
    schedule='@daily',
    start_date=datetime(2022, 1, 1, 12, 0, 0),
    catchup=False,
    tags=["test"]
) as dag:
    # create task 1

    @task(task_id="run_newspaper")
    def my_function():
        print(requests.get("http://youtube.com"))
        print("my_function")

    run_this = my_function()
```

I have tried this on my local environment and the requests works. However on airflow it is stuck on the print(requests.get("http://youtube.com")) which means the airflow is unable to make requests to a webpage. I was thinking that network needs to configured in someway in airflow but couldnt really find resources on it, could someone guide me?

Comment: Your DAG looks fine. how you are running Airflow?

Comment: I also couldn't reproduce the problem. if you are running it under airflow docker try to enter the worker container and run "wget http://youotube.com" to see if you have access

Comment: Thanks @PankajSingh I am running them by triggering the DAG manually through the airflow webserver. The task is then run by the airflow scheduler. I am using airflow through the PyPI package.

Comment: yeah @ozs could be something with my computer or airflow configuration

Comment: Have you tried to send the request using SimpleHTTPOperator?